# count number of shortest paths BOOST graph c++

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I'm trying to get the number of shortest paths from points 1 to 7.

I know there are many methods in the BOOST c ++ library like kruskal, dijkstra , r_c_shortest_path or just dfs/bfs....

The problem is that I understand that all these methods return only 1 way.

there is some method that pulls all the different paths to get from one point to another?

For example i have this:

`#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
using namespace boost;
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int, char*[])
{
    typedef adjacency_list<> Graph ;
    Graph g(10);
    typedef std::pair<int, int> E;
    const int num_nodes = 7;
    E edge_array[] = { E(1, 2), E(1, 3), E(2, 4), E(3, 4), E(2, 5),
      E(4, 5), E(4, 7), E(4, 6), E(5,7), E(6,7)
    };
    int weights[] = { 5,7,10,8,30,12,25,11,13,30 };
    boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vd, vd2; 
    typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor e;
    std::pair<e, bool> p[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        vd = edge_array[i].first;
        vd2 = edge_array[i].second;
        p[i] = add_edge(vd, vd2, g);
    }

    graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor s = source(p[0].first,g);
    graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor t = target(p[9].first,g);


//And now here i need to save all the posible shortest paths using:
//kruskal
template <class Graph, class OutputIterator, class P, class T, class R>
OutputIterator
kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree(Graph& g, OutputIterator tree_edges, 
    const bgl_named_params<P, T, R>& params = all defaults);


// dijkstra
template <typename Graph, typename P, typename T, typename R>
void
dijkstra_shortest_paths(Graph& g,
  typename graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor s,
  const bgl_named_params<P, T, R>& params);


//r_c_shortest_paths
r_c_shortest_paths( g,
                    vertex_index_map,
                    edge_index_map,
                    s,
                    t,
                    pareto_optimal_solutions,
                    pareto_optimal_resource_containers,
                    rc,
                    ref,
                    dominance,
                    la,
                    vis )

    return 0;
}`

summary: dont know how to get all the shorttest paths and save it for compare

I turn here because I can not get it out after several hours

thank you, greetings and sorry for my bad english